# Решаю задачи на языке python, но проверяющая программа не засчитывает ответ. Есть ли у меня ошибка в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Текст задачи:
Бизнесмен Василий после прочтения известной книги решил открыть новый бизнес — отгружать апельсины бочками. Партнёрам важно знать, сколько именно бочек апельсинов отгружается каждый день.

Мобильный телефон Василия поддерживает только транслит, поэтому он передаёт сообщения вида "n bochek". Например, "3 bochki" или "1 bochka".

Напишите программу, которая выбирает правильное слово (из "bochka" , "bochek" , "bochki" ) в зависимости от значения n.

Входные данные

Одно целое число n (0≤n≤1000).

Выходные данные

Соответствующая фраза на транслите
Примеры:
3 bochki
1 bochka
15 bochek

Мой код:

```
a = n//1000
b = n//100%10
c = n//10%10
d = n%10
n == ("a" + "b" + "c" + "d")
if (n != 11 and d == 1) or (n == 1 and d == 1):
    print(str(n) + " bochka")
if (d == 2) or (d == 3) or (d == 4):
    print(str(n) + " bochki")
if (d == 5) or (d == 6) or (d == 7) or (d == 8) or (d == 9) or (d == 0):
    print(str(n) + " bochek")
if n == 11:
    print(str(n) + " bochek")
```

Comment: Потому что она не проходит тесты, как минимум `11` `12` и тд

Comment: Не надо вставлять длинные куски кода в комментарий. Сделайте правки в вопросе

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за совет

Comment: все еще неправильно, например, для 12. Напишите цикл от 0 до 30 и в цикле выводите результат работы - увидите, на каких значениях неправильно - их там будет некоторое количество.

Comment: теперь я точно все сделал правильно. по крайней мере старался. Роман, спасибо за совет, но условиями задачи запрещается использование циклов

Comment: опять 12... не сходится, еще раз переделаю

Comment: Так сделайте цикл просто для проверки работы, а после проверки удалите цикл

Comment: @jfkvy234 опубликуйте свое решение как ответ. Если оно у вас появится :)

Comment: Да, хорошо, но сейчас у меня нет времени, чуть позже

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в коде несколько ошибок:

1.Намеренно или не специально вы не объявили значение переменной n перед объявлением a,b,c:

```
n = int(input())
a = n//1000
b = n//100%10
c = n//10%10
d = n%10
```

2.Вы не проверили результаты от 12-ти до 20-ти бочек, там у вас и будут ошибки:
12 bochki, 13 bochki, ...

Работающий код:

```
n = int(input())
if 10 <= n%100 <= 20: n = str(n) + ' bochek'
else:
    if n%10 == 1: n = str(n) + ' bochka'
    elif 1 <= n%10 <= 4: n = str(n) + ' bochki'
    else : n = str(n) + ' bochek'
print(n)
```

Comment: спасибо!
............

Comment: Поправочка – `/` это просто оператор деления. В Питоне втором результат будет целочисленным если оба аргумента in'ы, иначе в итоге float; в третьем этот оператор всегда даёт float. А оператор `//` в обоих версиях используется для целочисленного деления, даже если на входе 2 float'а.

Comment: Да, точно, перепутала с C#. Сейчас я всех введу в заблуждение своими решениями... :)

Answer (score 1):

```
def Translit(n):
    n = str(n) #преобразуем в строку что бы взять срезы по индексам
    endn = int(n[-1]) #возьмем последнюю цифру числа бочек
    endnn = int(n[-2:]) #возьмем две последних цифры числа бочек
    #print('endn: ', endn) #для детального проведения тестов
    #print('endnn: ', endnn) #для детального проведения тестов
    if (endn == 1) and (endnn != 11) and (endnn != 12) and (endnn != 13) and (endnn != 14):
        print(n+' bochka')
    if (endn == 2) or (endn == 3) or (endn == 4):
        print(n+' bochki')
    if (endn == 5) or (endn == 6) or (endn == 7) or (endn == 8) or (endn == 9) or (endn == 0) or (endnn == 11) or (endnn == 12) or (endnn == 13) or (endnn == 14):
        print(n+' bochek')

#сам тест
count = 0
while count <= 1000:
    Translit(count)
    count +=1
```

Comment: Скиньте пожалуйста сервис где вы решаете эти задания. Интересно.

Comment: Сириус.Курсы.........